# Accelerometer misalignment issue

Tags: acceleration

I have tri-axial data from an accelerometer, however, I know in retrospect that it was not aligned properly when placed on a mechanical arm. I know because when looking at the values at stationary instead of being 0,0 1g they were 0.4g, 0.5g,0.92g. I am trying to calibrate the data and the technique I have used has not completely realigned my data. Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I have read literature and apparently it is not straight forward as it seems ie considering 3 angles around the three axis. I am mainly interested in two axis however so I am prepared to do this approximately.

Comment: OK, so you have an rms gain error of 12.1%. You can turn the device around each axis until you get (g_x,0,0), (0,g_y,0) and (0,0,g_z). Those are your three gains. Correct each axis gain, then find a rotation matrix that can explain the remaining gain corrected output. If your device also suffers from offsets, then you need to find a way to make a measurement while it is in free fall.

Comment: @CuriousOne - There are a number of things you can't do to robotic arms. Destructive testing (e.g., putting them into free fall) is in general not a good idea on even the cheapest of robotic arms. Besides, while free fall will catch biases, it not catch misalignment or non-orthogonality errors.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Losen screw, remove accelerometer, drop accelerometer in calibration jig, attach accelerometer back to arm, tighten screw? You were not gentle on him either, though. I like that. :-)

Comment: There are (at least) three causes of misalignment and non-orthogonality: (1) The cheapo MEMS accelerometer one uses is just that, a cheapo MEMS accelerometer. The misalignment and non-orthogonality are built-in into the device. (2) The lab assistant who mounted the device made some dumb mistake and mounted it incorrectly. (Murphy's law at work.) (3) Every device, no matter how well-constructed, no matter how painstaking attached, is still going to have some errors of this sort. They might be small, but they are still present.

Comment: There are a forth and a fifth possibility: the device is broken and/or your readout code is buggy. Other than that you may have an infestation with microscopic black holes... but I would check that hypothesis last.

Comment: @branny12000 To 'calibrate' your data - are you using Euler angle rotations or quaternion math?

Comment: @branny12000 I should have added - I'm assuming your static check had the accel z axis vertical. z is somewhat close to 1 g, but the other two axes are off by a factor of two. That's huge. Too big for Euler corrections.

Comment: @David Hammen I agree MEMS = cheap = less than great performance. But the misalignment branny12000 is seeing is way beyond any MEMS misalignment spec I've seen.

Comment: @docscience - Absolutely. This was a mounting error, not an internal misalignment error. But still, that error should have been detected during testing.

Comment: @DavidHammen  I don't think it's an alignment error - assuming it is a triax unit that's being used. Even MEMS devices are not that bad

Comment: @branny12000 What's the manufacturer and part number of the accelerometer?

Comment: @docscience - If I stupidly mount the accelerometer 20 degrees of where it's supposed to be mounted, it's still a misalignment error. Some of the misalignment comes from the device itself. The rest of the misalignment comes from the technician who (incorrectly) attached it to the structure.

Comment: hi I just read your question. I am using  quaternion maths to correct for the error. At the moment it seems to be doing the job. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are calibrating your sensors and your algorithms before you put your device to actual use. (If you aren't, that you are seeing these issues is entirely your fault.) Misalignment and non-orthogonality issues are easily detected at this stage.

Presumably you are using a Kalman filter of some sort, or something more advanced. (If you aren't, I strongly suggest that you don't let your robot near anything of value.) After enough time has elapsed, a properly-constructed and properly-tuned Kalman filter can detect all kinds of errors that slipped past your initial calibration.

Do a literature search. There are articles upon articles that discuss calibration and Kalman filters.

Comment: static accelerometer readings - nothing to do with a Kalman filter even if branny12000 is using one.

Comment: @docscience - That's not correct. A Kalman filter can model all kinds of things in addition to position and velocity. The number of states in spacecraft Kalman filters can be astounding. In addition to the standard position, velocity, attitude, and attitude rate, they oftentimes try to estimate misalignments,  non-orthogonalities, biases, drift rates, and more.

Comment: For a robotics application a KF might be used to 'fuse' multiple sensor readings together to provide a best estimate of joint angle for example. Yes - RE Kalman invented a remarkable filter. But that's not the issue here. This guy's raw readings are off - before they are even fed to the filter, if there is one. His static measure with z vertical shows the other two axes reading nearly half a g.

Comment: @docscience - As I said in a parenthetical remark in my answer, they should have done some preflight testing (or the robotic equivalent thereof). A KF can appear to be quite magical, but they only can do so much. The more error one can eliminate beforehand, the better.

Comment: Hi guys. I am a little confused as I said I am aware that when the accelerometer was fastened to the arm it wasnt aligned correctly and was rotated slightly and so I didnt begin with 0 0 1g will a KF help me?

Comment: @branny12000 Is the accelerometer a triaxial unit, two dual axis units or 3 single axis devices? If it's triaxial, and you've only introduced a minor rotational alignment you can use a simple Euler transformation to correct. And that does not require a Kalman filter. But if misalignment is the issue, your static data suggests a gross misalignment. The numbers are not conformal to anything close to an orthogonal triaxial arrangement. To get half of a g on two of the axes and a full g on the z axis when z is vertical says you have a problem with the device or electronics.

Comment: @branny12000  A Kalman filter might be useful if you intend on using it as an observer in a feedback control system, and fusing other measurements such as joint encoders or pots, but you need to fix the measurement issue first - whether it's device failure, misalignment or electronics failure.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying... I need to realign my measurements before filtering! Thanks for clarification